# Adding custom Link to sharepoint 2013 Suite Bar

Tags: user-controls, sharepoint-2013

I have followed following links to add custom link to SharePoint 2013 Suite Bar. But I am not able to see the link on Suite bar. I have also changed the sequence attribute of Delegate control but still no luck. I have checked the sequence attribute by changing values like 10, 20, 30, 50, 90 and even 150. but no success. Do somebody know what the problem can be ?

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/11/04/adding-your-own-links-to-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Please add some code: either `Elements.xml` or the control's code itself would be helpful. I've used the author of the second link's approach and it worked for me. However the styling did not work, so I just did `writer.Write("<a href='#'">LINK</a>'")` instead.

Also, I suggest posting on sharepoint.stackexchange.com. I feel it's much better since it's a domain specific StackExchange site and I've seen SharePoint MVPs and top bloggers posting there.

Answer (score 0):

i know it might be too late.

in my case the problem was with the user control path

```
~/_controltemplates/15/<feature_name>/<user_control>.ascx
```